# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')with next.js project

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, npm-install

I wanted to try next.js for the first time, after I did the initial set up and created the next app, I followed the instruction in README which is th follow:

```
First, run the development server:
npm run dev
# or
yarn dev
# or
pnpm dev
```

**Then I got this error: **

> Server Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading
> 'useContext')
>
> This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will
> be displayed in the terminal window. Call Stack Object.useContext
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/forSal/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js
> (1618:21) useContext
> ../.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/pages/_document.js
> (707:105) renderWithHooks
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js
> (5658:16) renderIndeterminateComponent
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js
> (5731:15) renderElement
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js
> (5946:7) renderNodeDestructiveImpl
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js
> (6104:11) renderNodeDestructive
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js
> (6076:14) renderIndeterminateComponent
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js
> (5785:7) renderElement
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js
> (5946:7) renderNodeDestructiveImpl
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js
> (6104:11) renderNodeDestructive
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js
> (6076:14) renderContextProvider
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js
> (5920:3) renderElement
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js
> (6017:11) renderNodeDestructiveImpl
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js
> (6104:11) renderNodeDestructive
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js
> (6076:14) renderContextProvider
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js
> (5920:3) renderElement
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js
> (6017:11) renderNodeDestructiveImpl
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js
> (6104:11) renderNodeDestructive
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js
> (6076:14) retryTask
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js
> (6528:5) performWork
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js
> (6576:7) 
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js
> (6902:12) scheduleWork
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js
> (77:3) startWork
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js
> (6901:3) 
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js
> (6996:5) new Promise  Object.renderToReadableStream
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js
> (6949:10) renderToString
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js
> (63:55) 
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js
> (886:112) NextTracerImpl.trace
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js
> (65:20) Object.renderToHTML
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js
> (886:57) async doRender
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js
> (936:34) async
> cacheEntry1.responseCache.get.incrementalCache.incrementalCache
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js
> (1059:28) async
> file:///Users/xiaoxuanlyu/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/next/dist/server/response-cache/index.js
> (83:36)

This is before I did anything to this project, everything come from the default settings. So I'm confused why it cannot run.

I checked my react and next.js version, try update all libraries, did not work

Comment: can you provide code sandbox link or your code to look at and figure at where the problem is

Comment: What's your node version, and are you on MacOS, Windows...?