# get an error after initial setup with create-next-app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, create-react-app

this question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76019989/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-usecontextwith-next-js-pro) before and there were no answers so I ask again.

I make a next project with `npx create-next-app project-name --ts` and after it finishes it job and run `npm run dev` without any changes to the source code I get this error:

```
    Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
Object.useContext
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js (1618:21)
useContext
node_modules\next\dist\pages\_document.js (707:105)
renderWithHooks
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5658:16)
renderIndeterminateComponent
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5731:15)
renderElement
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5946:7)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
finishClassComponent
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5688:3)
renderClassComponent
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5696:3)
renderElement
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5943:7)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
renderContextProvider
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5920:3)
renderElement
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6017:11)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
renderContextProvider
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5920:3)
renderElement
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6017:11)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
retryTask
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6528:5)
performWork
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6576:7)
<unknown>
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6902:12)
scheduleWork
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (77:3)
startWork
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6901:3)
<unknown>
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6996:5)
new Promise
<anonymous>
Object.renderToReadableStream
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6949:10)
renderToString
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js (63:55)
<unknown>
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js (886:112)
NextTracerImpl.trace
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js (65:20)
Object.renderToHTML
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js (886:57)
async doRender
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js (936:34)
async cacheEntry1.responseCache.get.incrementalCache.incrementalCache
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js (1059:28)
async
file:///X:/.Programming/jukify_next/node_modules/next/dist/server/response-cache/index.js (83:36)
```

I'm not using `useContext` anywhere in my code since I didn't change the initial code that create-next-app provides.
I tried to make a new project on other devices but still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

so I decided to make a next.js app without `create-next-app` like this:
`npm install next react react-dom` > `mkdir pages` > Create a new file called index.js inside the pages directory with the following contents:

```
import React from 'react';

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to my Next.js app!</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

add `"scripts": { "dev": "next" }` to `package.json` and run `npm run dev` and again got the exact same error! so I guess it is because of next.js?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).